# The best way to say "when we arrived"

Tags: phrase-choice

Are there definitely wrong versions in the list below?

Which version (and why) is the best one?

_____, we were asked to take a placement test.

1. On arriving
2. Upon arriving
3. On arrival
4. Upon arrival
5. Having arrived
6. As soon as we arrived

My favourite one is the 5th one (*having arrived*), but I am not sure it is the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are all good.

My choice would be `On arrival`

They all give the sense of the first thing that we were asked to do after we'd arrived was complete the placement test.

So I think it's whichever floats your boat.